# how to uninstall genymotion in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uninstall, genymotion

I have downloaded and unstalled genymotion in my ubuntu 18.04 version laptop and i have deleted the downloaded file of genymotion after intalling and now i wanted to uninstall it. Help me to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems this is a proprietary software, installed via a .bin file. It is not using the deb packaging format, nor is it available in the repositories... You should ask the company behind this software...